# CSS – link:hover color inheritance issue

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I am really confused by what is happening here. I am wondering why the link is white when the cursor is within the button but NOT directly on the link? I want it to be red while cursor is within button boundaries.
 
I think that this happening is because at that point, the page is inheriting from the declared .links:a color value, but I am wondering how do I get it to override that? The .links:hover doesn't seem to transfer inheritance to .links a:hover (?) 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
.links a{
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.links:hover{
  background-color:white;
  color:red;
}

.links a:hover{
  background-color:white;
  color:red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3dujymLk/1/

Answer (score 2):

Your rules are working exactly the way you wrote them. If you want the `a` text to be red while hovering over the entire `div`, you need a rule for that. Add something like this:

```
.links:hover a {
    color: red;
}
```

If it isn't obvious, this controls the text-color of the link while hovering over the div.

Comment: Mhmmmm, I see. Thank you.
It seems that didn't think about the fact that <a> is a class of its own, hence it requires specific behavior rules for different instances. I was counting on text color to transfer to the link for some reason, n00b mistake.

Comment: There's a lot more than just inheritance and cascade when it comes to CSS. Check out this article to learn about CSS specificity, which is how the browser determines which styles to apply to what elements. https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/